# The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open

Tags: windows, dll

Whenever I tried to copy 4 files into my bin folder, after stopping the main service, I am getting an error with one file (TexteDll). The error is:

```
Cannot copy TexteDll: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file 
with a user-mapped section open
```

It may be due to some system locking. Or perhaps another process is using this DLL. When I googled, I found that rebooting the system may resolve this.

Can anybody suggest a cause or solution for this? I inspected the properties of TexteDll (general, version, security, etc). Everything appears normal.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302698/system-io-exception-error-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file

Comment: there are actually many more 'duplicates' of the question (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818076/why-do-i-get-file-is-used-by-another-process-errors-when-i-debug-within-visual) - problem is that every time the root cause is something different.

Comment: next time try to use "process explorer" from microsoft's site. It has a feature called "find handle". search your file in there and it will show you which process has a handle on that file. Then you can start investigating why that program has that access. BTW, stopping a service does not necessarily mean the executable that hosts service will end. An executable may host multiple services. In a worst case, many .net services that use huge amounts of memory tends to terminate after releasing that memory which happens sometimes minutes after service's stop event.

Comment: Hehehe Visual Studio was locking my DLL. Closed Visual Studio and tried to rebuild the Solution and it worked.

Comment: This is obviously a memory conflict. A particular 'instance' of the object has some allocated bit memory mapped, then later finds that the memory (statically?) allocated to it, has already been mapped elsewhere, likely with a different level of system access.

Comment: Thanks, Leniel. I had the problem running Unity with a Visual Studio open. I closed Unity since that locks all C#/C dll's. Still one DLL failing to be replaced. I had left the VS solution open, which caused the lock.

Comment: rebooting solved the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.IO.Exception error: "The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302698/system-io-exception-error-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-fil)

Comment: If the error is caused by a git diff locking files, that won't be the case with Git 2.23+ (Q3 2019). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229750/6309)

Comment: In my case Oxygen XML may have left a process hanging around accessing the file and the only way I could resolved the problem was rebooting my PC to make sure all processes accessing the file were off.

Answer (score 197):

In my case it was the Explorer that was locking the DLL that was been compiled in the Debug folder... Strange, isn't it?

I found out using a tool called Unlocker.

Had to delete with Unlocker, even when it was saying that there was no lock over the file, and I couldn't delete the folder until I didn't delete that single file...

After that it compiled.

EDIT:

I found out why in my case this was happening. I had the DLL opened in a text editor inside Visual Studio...

Comment: I had the dlo open in one of my many visual studio windows open also.  Thanks for posting that update.

Comment: Same thing, somehow the danged DLL was open in a text window in the editor.

Comment: Full disclosure: the link to "Unlocker" is total spyware.  It installs all sorts of toolbars and crap, even if you uncheck all the boxes saying you don't want them.

Comment: same for me DLL was open in VS.   +1

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) instread of Unlocker. Once PE is running, go to Find -> Find Handle or Dll and paste the name of the locked file. It will show which process locked it. Kill it if you are sure it's ok to do it and the problem should be solved.

Comment: In my case, the .dll was being held onto by FxCop.  I closed FxCop and it was able to compile.

Comment: For me, the Services window was the culprit.

Comment: I unchecked 'read only' on the folder - recursively - and rebooted - that released the file lock and fixed it.

Comment: It was a git diff for me.

Comment: I oppened the dll in vs by mistake and forgot it .. you saved my day. thanks

Comment: I unloaded my project and reloaded it. Typical jank in VS.

Comment: !!!!!!!!!!!WARNING!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Please do be careful to download the Unlocker from file hippo, it contains adware and could be dangerous to use.

Answer (score 79):

- Sometimes when you double click on a warning about the referenced
  assembly version mismatch between two or more projects you forget to
  close the assembly view window and it stays there among other
  tabs... so you end up with the assembly being locked by VS
  itself and it took me quite a lot of time to figure that out :)

  Be careful with the power VS provides ;)
- Another dummy scenario. Sometimes simply deleting the whole obj
  folder or just the file warned as the locked one helps out with this
  crappy error.

Comment: sorted it for me... I even did a system restart but VS reopened the assembly view window. Closing all tabs did the job. Cheers

Comment: Incredible, thanks for this. Totally shocked it was because I had one of the files open as a tab in VS!

Answer (score 42):

close all documents on VS and try to rebuild again. If it doesn't work restart VS. This problem is related to lock of DLL files.

Comment: same, some weirdness with VS. restart sorted it for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Strange thing in my particular circumstance. I had executed my exe standalone, outside of the VS environment. Left it running overnight (memory test - it passed), shut it down in the morning, a couple of small code changes, and suddenly couldn't finish my build because of this. Weird how this memory seemed to conflict like this.

Comment: Nasty, thanks, an open document was causing the error, what BS!

Comment: "Close all Documents" and rebuild actually worked for me ! :o

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue. How I resolved it was:

1. Open "Task Manager"
2. End task "Explorer.exe"
3. Click "File" --> Create new task -- Type in "explorer.exe" --> OK
4. Clean my project and it works

Comment: I also had to restart the Explorer process from Task Manager. In my case, I had viewed the "problematic" file in the "Preview" area of the Explorer. This also seems to lock files from time to time without ever releasing them. Closing all Explorer windows did not help. Had to restart the process.

Comment: Closing "Explorer.exe" was my solution as well. Though in my case I have enabled the option to "Launch folder windows in a separate process" so there is no requirement to relaunch the Explorer shell.

Answer (score 16):

Close visual studio, delete bin , debug release folder, and start visual studio project again.
that fixed my problem

Answer (score 15):

I am a developer and do not like apps injected to Registery like Unlocker.
I used [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)  which process locked my dll `Find > Find Handle or Dll [Ctrl-F]` and killed the process.

Comment: Found it was locked by a VS process that did not die when VS was closed.

Comment: Even after DevEnv was closed and Task Manager did not show it, Process Explorer showed several instances of DevEnv Suspended. Kill these and it worked.

Comment: This is the most correct answer, since it shows _how_ to find which process is locking the file, rather than just saying "in my case it was due to X". Every developer on Windows would benefit from adding procexp and procmon to their toolbelt!

Comment: This is the right answer! devenv.exe was holding even after exiting, just used `taskkill /pid 1234 /f`

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem and in my case it appeared that existing output file was locked by other application.

You can check which application is locking your output file with OpenedFilesView:
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html

Answer (score 10):

Others have already established that this error is due to another application having a lock on the file. Just wanted to point out that `git diff` locks files as well until you quit out of it. That's what caused this in my case.

Comment: Same issue for me. Forgot I hadn't quit the diff. Unfortunately, I didn't see this answer until I closed a bunch of other windows and saw it was still in a diff. Then was making sure I didn't post a dupe answer so +1 :)

Comment: @codeMagic Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) will avoid that trap. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229750/6309)

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had to kill a hanging `MSBuild.exe` process that was locking the file (it was there even after I closed Visual Studio).

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

It has been [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146550/6309) in 2016 by [Andrew Cuthbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529997/andrew-cuthbert) that `git diff` locks files as well until you quit out of it.

That is still the case for `git diff`, but it won't be the case with Git 2.23 (Q3 2019), for *external* diff tools (as reported by [Burkart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051245/burkart) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658354/the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with-a-user-mapped-section/57229750#comment125914103_57229750)).

See [commit 3aef54e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aef54e8b82bc02b9cebbb7d0bed8911ee0418e3) (11 Jul 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d9beb46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d9beb468e6d0c493eed00e365d90a69127488caa), 25 Jul 2019)</sup>

> ### `diff`: `munmap()` file contents before running external diff

> When running an external diff from, say, a `diff tool`, it is safe to
> assume that we want to write the files in question.
> On Windows, that means that there cannot be any other process holding an open handle to
> said files, or even just a mapped region.
>
> So let's make sure that `git diff` itself is not holding any open handle to the files in question.
>
> In fact, we will just release the file pair right away, as the external diff uses the files we just wrote, so we do not need to hold the file contents in memory anymore.
>
> This fixes [git-for-windows#1315](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1315)

---

Running "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d5e35329dd5305d611478e8d5076a8ca75e25f0d/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> while allowing external diff in a state with unmerged paths used to segfault, which has been corrected with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

See [commit d668518](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d66851806ff25c6afdb4650d8292a50d5ca0ea6d), [commit 2469593](https://github.com/git/git/commit/246959346f3407cb047c3d46ed9c44da84bd0b29) (06 Nov 2020) by [Jinoh Kang (`iamahuman`)](https://github.com/iamahuman).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d5e3532](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5e35329dd5305d611478e8d5076a8ca75e25f0d), 21 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/246959346f3407cb047c3d46ed9c44da84bd0b29): allow passing `NULL` to `diff_free_filespec_data()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jinoh Kang</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>

> Commit [3aef54e8b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aef54e8b82bc02b9cebbb7d0bed8911ee0418e3) ("`diff`: `munmap()` file contents before running external diff", Git v2.22.1) introduced calls to `diff_free_filespec_data` in `run_external_diff,` which may pass `NULL` pointers.
>
> Fix this and prevent any such bugs in the future by making `diff_free_filespec_data(NULL)` a no-op.
>
> Fixes: [3aef54e8b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3aef54e8b82bc02b9cebbb7d0bed8911ee0418e3) ("diff: munmap() file contents before running external diff")

Comment: As I understand it, these fixes apply to _external_ diff tools only whereas the "integrated" diff on the command line still locks the diffed files. Observed in Git 2.35.1.

Comment: @Burkart Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 6):

Are you running any Anti-virus software. It's possible that the AV software (or some other piece of software) was reading the file using the file mapping APIs which caused the problem.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions posted here worked for me. It was devenv.exe (Visual Studio) locking the file, but if I restarted it, it would re-lock it.

Bizarrely, Windows wouldn't let me Delete the files (to Recycle Bin), but Shift+Delete (permanent delete) worked.

Answer (score 3):

Close the Visual Studio and Run it as administrator. It's fixed my problem.

Comment: I was getting this error while building a shiny app in rstudio, so many of these answers weren't helpful to me. But I saw this and tried restarting rstudio as administrator, and it worked. Then when I went back to running as user it worked again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Restart did not work for me. There was a process called VBSCompiler was running in task manager. I had to end the process to fix this error.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the obj folder and rebuilding worked for me

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to close out of all instances of VS and to kill any hanging devenv.exe processes.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing these errors when building Dot Net applications with Ant.

In my case it was our corporate backup software, the Symantec DLO Agent. Stopping it and excluding the directory in my antivirus software and closing Visual Studio seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

in my case deleted the obj folder in project root and rebuild project solved my problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me after I have changed the project target CPU from '`Any CPU`' to '`X64`' and then back to '`Any CPU`'.

 Solved it by deleting the `Obj` folder (for beginners: don`t worry about deleting the obj folder, it will be recreated again in the next compile).

Comment: Tried many other suggestions, the file was not locked but VS kept saying it was. This was the only one which worked to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different one.  Seems like it can happen due to a file handle being in use.  This is why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54446649/1167442) works, I believe.  For me, I had type `more project.csproj` from the command line, and forgotten I had left it open.  So the handle was locked for reading.
Sysinternals has a neat command line tool called `handle` if you are partial to the command line.  You can type `handle <partial name of whatever file or folder you want>` and it will tell you what program (if any) is using it.

[*Handle by Sysinternals*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow a simple restart solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solutions but they did not work for me. Few steps that I followed:

- Closing all VS instances and opening again.
- Killing build.exe and explorer.exe processes.
- Deleting bin folder in projects.

What worked for me is -
**Restarting My Machine.**

Another solution:

- go to the solution folder.
- check the properties, and remove read-only property if there.
- click and apply to all the subfolders.
- open VS again, clean + build solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error and it turned out the issue was FxCop was running against my project.  I closed FxCop and then I could compile again.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web application deleting files in Temporary ASP.NET Files folder could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using profilers like AQ Time, these may also be locking the file. The solution in this case would be to restart the profiler or simply unload/load the assembly in question from the profiler. 
For AQ Time I noticed that it's releasing the file after some time, but I can't for the life of me tell what that timeout is. 
Seems to be random

Answer (score 0):

My issue was also solved by sifting through the Process Explorer. However, the process I had to kill was the MySQL Notifier.exe that was still running after closing all VS and SQL applications.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solved this issue.

Someone had one project in my solution set to use x64 CPU in the build configuration. Changing it to Any CPU caused the build to use a new folder. I still don't know what process had (has) a lock on that file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with visual micro on Visual Studio 2019. It was complaining about the `\_vm\compile.vmps.xml` file. Unable to delete/modify it perhaps. I fixed this issue by deleting the `_vm` folder in the root directory of the project and rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to publish API to my local IIS, I fixed it by simply deleting the causing file in the IIS target folder and publish the API again, it seemed like it corrupted or something.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me on Window 10, Visual Studio 2022, Visual Basic project. Process Explorer "Find Handle/DLL" shows me 4 lines of devenv.exe locking the file.

Besides killing devenv.exe, I can also fix the issue by simply deleting the folder that contains the locked file (in this case it's bin\Debug). It's strange because I'm not allowed to deleted the locked file, but I can delete the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was still an "invisible" instance of VS2022 (devenv.exe) running. It was listed in Task Manager with Status=Suspended but no corresponding window was visible on the taskbar or anywhere else. After killing that process the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but after closing all opened tabs and files, exiting VS, then opening it back up, running a new build, I still got the error. I had to clean solution, then build for the error to go away.

Build >> Clean Solution