# Visual studio Project creation issue

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Ok bear with me because i am frustrated beyond belief right now.

go back about 30 minutes ago, i create a VB windows forms application. cool, nothing out of the ordinary only i make a big mistake and decide to start again. so i close the solution, delete the project folder and go to start again, only now i'm presented with

"requested operation cant be performed on file with user-mapped section open"

ok i think, there's obviously something still reading it or whatever, so i close VS completely and restart.. no avail. log off and try again. nothing. restart the computer. still nothing. what is causing this issue? i can create a C# Windows Forms Application without a frigging problem. everything BUT a VB WFA. what do i do? i'm in no real position to re-install VS right now or i'd have started 20 minutes ago. i really need a helping hand here please

Comment: Can you open a second copy of VS, attach its debugger to the first copy, and look at the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658354/the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with-a-user-mapped-section

Comment: the project folder is not the only one VS creates.  It creates files in `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft` for stuff.  It also tries to keep track where you left off for crash recovery, so something points to something and then maybe back to something else which no longer exists.  see if the links or links in the links help