# Android Studio Flutter debugging FileSystemException

Tags: android-studio, debugging, flutter, dart

I am developing a **Flutter** application in **Android Studio**. When I place a breakpoint somewhere in the code it gets hit and execution stops, but after half a second the application exits with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'build\app.dill.track.dill.incremental.dill' (OS Error: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.
, errno = 1224)
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:364:9)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
#2      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#5      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
#6      Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)
#7      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#8      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#9      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
Unhandled exception:
SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: The pipe is being closed.
, errno = 232), port = 0
#0      _rootHandleUncaughtError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1112:29)
#1      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#2      _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#3      _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

If I run application without debugging it works normally. Has anyone had similar error and solved it successfully?

Comment: run `flutter clean` and then build the project.

Comment: @anmol.majhail It doesn't help. I still receive the same error.

Comment: Possible replicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658354/the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-file-with-a-user-mapped-section and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302698/system-io-exception-error-the-requested-operation-cannot-be-performed-on-a-fil

Comment: @Bill Visit those links and tell us if they help you.

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint seems to work as expected. What happens here looks like a function in the app expects a value that wasn't provided after the breakpoint. Debug the app by checking if there's any function expecting a value that's blocked by the breakpoint.